# How do cut any selection vba

Tags: excel, vba

how do I select an entire line and copy to another sheet from a line selection?

I want from the user to select one or more lines delete or cut the complete line
tks for help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't users just select rows and use keyboard Delete or right click menu as well as copy/paste. Sounds like Excel is not the best app for your requirements. If you need to save and manage data, use a database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, try that in vba

Sub SCUT ()

Selection.Cut Destination:=Sheets("Other_sheet").Range("A1")

End sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).